# Quebra de linha Json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, jade

Estou tentando desenvolver um sistema com Node.js e estou tentando listar os dados do banco de dados na minha tabela, porém os dados ficam todos juntos dessa forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Eu ainda não entendo muito de Json, será que é porque ele está dessa forma?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a minha função que faz a listagem:

```
 Usuario.find(function (err, data) {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }

                res.render("usuarios/index", {lista: data});
            });
```

E essa é minha página:

```
extends ../layout

block content
        h1 Página de Usuários
        br
        br
        a(href="/" title="Home") Voltar
        br
        br
        table(class="table well")
            thead
            tr
            th ID:
            th Nome:
            th Login:
            th Senha:
            th Data:

        tbody
            each valor, i in lista
                tr
                    td #{valor.id}
                    td #{valor.nome}
```

CMD:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: estás a usar `Jade` certo?

Comment: o que dá `console.log(typeof data, data);` dentro desse ` Usuario.find()`?

Comment: editei a pergunta e coloquei uma imagem com o que aparece

Comment: Dá um inspect na tabela e mostre como ele está sendo renderizado. Só um adendo, a forma como o JSON está não interfere na forma como os dados são exibidos na tela

Comment: Realmente esqueci de identar, não sabia que tinha isso no Jade. Problema resolvido

Comment: Coloque uma resposta para que eu possa marca-la como solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É necessário identar os `th` associados aos `tr` (no seu caso, do `thead`), caso contrário o Jade interpretará como todos estando no mesmo nível em relação ao `thead`.

```
table(class="table well")
    thead
        tr
            th ID:
            th Nome:
            th Login:
            th Senha:
            th Data:
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.